# How to keep cell text height large when using adjustbox?

Tags: tables, fontsize, adjustbox

When I restrict the table width to 0.7\textwidth it also reduces the size of the font. I would like the table to show in the center of the page but for the text to be large enough to be readable.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{adjustbox}{width=0.7\textwidth}
    \medskip\noindent
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
                Some text. & lsibyg gihebg fiehbg etin vtn osuing iostnugetnug etouhg otunhoeuthg thgu ituhg iotuhg ieuth guoierthg touhg uoth ut guotg uwht owuht \\\hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{ajustbox}
\end{center}
        
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
                Some text. & lsibyg gihebg fiehbg etin vtn osuing iostnugetnug etouhg otunhoeuthg thgu ituhg iotuhg ieuth guoierthg touhg uoth ut guotg uwht owuht \\\hline 
\end{tabular} \\
\end{document}
```

Comment: never scale tables with adjustbox or `\scalebox` etc. The results, as you found, are never going to be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not need adjust box. Just prescribe table width and for the second column use "paragraph" column type, for example `p{<width>}` or `X` column type defined in the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{0.7\linewidth}{|l|X|} % <---
    \hline
    Some text. & lsibyg gihebg fiehbg etin vtn osuing iostnugetnug etouhg otunhoeuthg thgu ituhg iotuhg ieuth guoierthg touhg uoth ut guotg uwht owuht \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l|X|}    % <---
    \hline
    Some text. & lsibyg gihebg fiehbg etin vtn osuing iostnugetnug etouhg otunhoeuthg thgu ituhg iotuhg ieuth guoierthg touhg uoth ut guotg uwht owuht \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

Comment: Thanks Zarco, works perfectly.